# Are type hint and default param value also method signature?

Tags: php, class, oop, interface, method-signature

Example :
The interface is

```
public function doFoo($bar);
```

Can I have a class implementing the interface with method

```
public function doFoo(array $bar = array('test')) { }
```

What does the method signature mean in PHP?

Is it just the method name and parameter name ?
Or, type hinting and default values for parameters also included ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I've just tried it. It seems that the default value is not a method signature for php >= 5.3.0, and type hint is included in method signature. Okay, I think case solved

Comment: ^ Yes :) You got it! That's exactly how it is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for an argument isn't fixed with a interface (To clarify: The value isn't fixed, but if the interface has a default value then the class which implements the interface also needs a default value, but the value is not fixed by the interface).

However when an interface defines a method with a type hint the class must use the same type hint! You can also see this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

And a quote from there:

> An **interface**, together **with type-hinting**, provides a good way to make sure that a particular object **contains particular methods**. See instanceof operator and type hinting.

Answer (score 0):

You can [type-hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in several ways. The formatting of a method signature in PHP goes:

`class -> type -> variable -> default value`

Thus, you can hint that a param must be an instance of a class like:

`function foo(someClass $bar)`

or you can merely specify that that param must be `callable` like:

`function foo(callable $bar)`

Similarly, you can type hint the an array like you did above.

A param not being an instance of the class you specified throws a fatal error.